# runat="server" breaks my jQuery - datapicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runatserver

The runat="server" is breaking my jquery. I have two input, but for testing purpose added runat="server" in only one of those. Actually , I need to add on both.

Below you can find JS script to trigger the datetimepicker:
note: dateTo has runat="server" set and tried to change the way JS trying to get its ID, but still not working.

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $("#dateFrom").datetimepicker();
            $("#<%=dateTo%>").datetimepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Here you can find the HTML input using runat="server" or not into asp.net code.

```
    <tr>
        <td>
             <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" value="" class="dateFrom" />
        </td>
        <td >
             <input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" runat="server" value="" class="dateTo" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Does anybody has any idea,hint.....?
thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ClientID` to get the generated `Id` of a server side control:

```
$("#<%=dateTo.ClientID%>").datetimepicker();
```

ASP.NET will generate a specific `id` attribute that is *different* from the `id` attribute of the server side control, so you need to use the generated value in order to access it from jQuery.

Comment: This spells real trouble (see: ugliness) for separating resources and ties client side script to page contents, although you could start passing around arguments to functions etc. in this format, but still.

Comment: @Grant - True. Part of the leaky abstraction of webforms :(

Comment: Indeed! A 'neat' trick, but the sooner this disappears the better. "While we provided a way of supplying the developer with the client side ID, with the growth of client side scripting this solution has become some what hacky." http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Comment: @Grant - I can't agree more, but for those stuck with webforms and want to manipulate server side controls with client side script, there aren't that many other options (I suppose one could give a unique class name per such control, but that's even more hacky).

Comment: Yes, no more "but"'s from me: this is a credible answer for the OP in that situation.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're supplying class names, I suggest simply using those.

```
$(function(){
    $(".dateTo, .dateFrom").datetimepicker();
});
```

Alternatively, you could give any "date" field on your form a class of "date" and use that:

```
$(function(){
    $(".date").datetimepicker();
});
```

This is a common pattern for client-side validation, and also allows you to provide context clues through styling with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4 you can set the `ClientIDMode` attribute to `Static`. This will prevent the framework from changing the element's ID:

```
<input type="text" id="dateTo" name="dateTo" runat="server" 
       ClientIDMode="Static" class="dateTo" value=""  />
```

Comment: @DaveBaghdanov - True, however the generated ID is still not likely to be `dateTo` in your example. It just means it is less likely to dynamically change, in case you hard code the client ID into your `.js` files.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET will treat the inputs as server-side controls when `runat=server` is added, and this will result in transformed identifiers of those inputs so that they start with a container prefix (something like `ctl00_`), hence 'breaking' your jQuery selectors.

If you're using .NET 4 then you can disable these transformations by altering the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx). Otherwise you will need to include the prefix in your selectors, or refactor your selectors to be independent of ID and somewhat distinct for selection by other means.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get correct client id for server controls

```
$('[id$=dateTo]').datetimepicker();
```